# Adding extra string to comma separated values using shell

Tags: shell

Please help using `shell` script for below statement

My **input** is below

```
a=abc,def,ghi
```

My **output** should be as below

```
a=h.abc,h.def,h.ghi
```

How can I achieve this in shell scripting please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
export IFS=","
    words="abc,def,ghi"
    for word in $words; do
      echo "h.$word"
    done
```

If you want to print output in the same line use `echo -n`

Comment: I wouldn't *export* IFS. In this case, it doesn't harm, but in general, it's too dangerous, because a possible child process would see the changed value. Also, IFS should be set back to the original value afterwards.

Comment: @NaveenSrikanth : While the approach outlined by Java basically works, it would break if your input contains quoted strings containing commas, for instance if you have `a=abc,"de,ef",ghi`. In general, I advise to parse CSV files with a real CSV parser. It's much safer.

Comment: I am getting output as h. abc .Why is this ?. Hiw can I overcme

Comment: You need output like h.abc rt?

Comment: Yes I need as h.abc,h.def,h.ghi and the output is going to next line

Comment: so you need to use echo -n-> echo -n "h.$word"

Comment: -n is working thanks alot but still there is an space out is showing as       
 "h. abc"

Comment: You may have space before your input ( words=" abc,def,ghi"). I just ran it. I didn't see the space

Comment: Agree space was there in input. But when I write to an file and when I read again , were not there . Is ther any prob here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160288/discussion-between-java-and-naveen-srikanth).